# Adding text to a plot

Tags: r, visualization

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- 0.5*dnorm(x,0,1)
plot(x,y1,type="l",bty="L",xlab="X",ylab="dnorm(X)")
points(x,y2,type="l",col="red")
polygon(c(x,rev(x)),c(y2,rev(y1)),col="skyblue")
```

[image]

I want to label the difference between the two curves at -3, -2, -1, ..., 3. I have tried using just the `text` function where I manually adjust the coordinates one by one and then type in the difference between the two curves. Is there an more efficient way of doing this so that the difference between the two curves is displayed clearly?

Comment: You could probably use `ggplot2` and `annotate` function. Looks seemingly easy in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- 0.5*dnorm(x,0,1)
plot(x,y1,type="l",bty="L",xlab="X",ylab="dnorm(X)")
points(x,y2,type="l",col="red")
polygon(c(x,rev(x)),c(y2,rev(y1)),col="skyblue")

idx <- which(x %in% -3:3)
text(x[idx], y1[idx], labels = round(y1[idx], 2))
text(x[idx], y2[idx], labels = round(y2[idx], 2), col="red")
```

[image]